# Help to check a proof about local prime ideal being principal?

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field, call it's ring of integers $\mathcal O_K$ and take a - possibly nonprincipal - prime ideal $\mathfrak q$. I have shown that $\mathcal O_K$ is Noetherian integral domain and every prime ideal is maximal.

Define the local ring $$\mathcal O_{\mathfrak q} = \{ x/y \in K | x,y \in \mathcal O_K, y \not\in \mathfrak q \}$$ I have shown that it has a unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak m = \mathfrak q \mathcal O_{\mathfrak q}$, all ideals are linearly ordered and that it too is Noetherian.

> I want to prove that $\mathfrak m$ is principal - I made an attempt but I am worried my proof is wrong

Here is my approach: Take $x \in \mathfrak m$. Either $(x) = \mathfrak m$ or we can take $y \in \mathfrak m \setminus (x)$ in which case we have $(x) \subset (y) \subset \mathfrak m$. We can continue this so by the Noetherian property we must eventually find an element such that $(\pi) = \mathfrak m$.

Answer (score 1):

Chose $\alpha \in \mathfrak{q} \setminus \mathfrak{q}^2$ and show $\mathfrak{m}=(\alpha)$.

Proof: Let $\beta \in \mathfrak{q} \setminus \mathfrak{q}^2$ then

$$\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=\frac{P}{Q}$$ where $P$ and $Q$ are ideals relatively prime to $\mathfrak{q}$. To get numbers let $S$ be an ideal relatively prime to $\mathfrak{q}$ such that $QS$ is principle, say $=(\tau)$.
So $\tau \not \in \mathfrak{q}$ and 
 $$\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=\frac{PS}{QS}=\frac{PS}{(\tau)}$$ thus

$\tau \frac{\alpha}{\beta} \not \in \mathfrak{q}$ Let $\sigma =\tau \frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ then 
$$\frac{\alpha}{\beta}= \frac{\sigma}{\tau}.$$

Comment: Thanks for this! Could anyone tell me how we know that $P,Q$ exist? And I have seen a proof that we can multiply up by an ideal to produce a principal ideal in Hecke but it require a difficult work with polynomials and gauss lemma -- I would except any proof to involve tricky stuff like this which makes me worried I've missed something in my original proof attempt.

Comment: @Brennan.Tobias just factor $\alpha$ and $\beta$ into prime ideals and cancel the common factor of $\mathfrak{q}$.